# Python request not attaching client certificate on the HTTPS session

Tags: ssl, soap, python-requests, zeep

I've implemented a SOAP client in python with the *zeep* library. Some of the endpoints require client-side certificate authentication, thus the need to attach the certificate to the python requests's session.
After googling around, I've come up with:

```
    from zeep import Client
    from zeep.transports import Transport
    from django.utils import timezone
    import requests
    ......
    session = requests.Session()    
    session.verify = False
    session.cert= ('pat_to_cert.pem','path_to_privKey.pem')
    transport = Transport(session=session)
    ....
    client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport)
    send = getattr(service, service_name)
    result = send(**data)
```

Debbugging the TLS handshake, the server issues a *Certificate Request*, but the client replies with an empty certificate. I've already checked the .pem files with openssl with no errors.

Is it possible that python's requests is not attaching the certificate because it does not recognize the server name? How can I enforce to use this certificate for every request?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are setting `session.verify = False` that's why TLS verification is disabled.

what you need to do is to set:

```
session.verify = 'path/to/my/certificate.pem'
```

Also, Alternatively, instead of using `session.verify` you can use `session.cert` if you just want to use an TLS client certificate:

```
session.verify = True
session.cert = ('my_cert', 'my_key')
```

please check the documentation for more details: https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html

hope this helps

Comment: Verify is only for Server certificate I guess, the issue is related with client-side certificate.

Comment: well, yes it is. have you tried `session.verify = True` with `session.cert= ('pat_to_cert.pem','path_to_privKey.pem')`

Comment: i updated my answer for it as well. did it solve the issue? please let us know. if yes then please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately not! I've used your second version:
client.transport.session.verify = True
client.transport.session.cert =('file.cert', 'file.pem')